# Jquery call var from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the `maxdata` variable if it is in the .on change function
 does someone knows how I can use it in .click function I want to use
 it in a if statement to alert something.

If someone knows how to do this can you please tell me I have tried `var window.maxdata` and than tried to call it from the .click function but still doesn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
     $("#vakgebied").on('change', function()
    { 
            var current = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
            //alert(current);
             var maxdata = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-max');
            //alert(maxdata);
            $("#maxwoorden").text("MaxWoordenPerDag: "+ maxdata);


     }); 

    $("#berekenen").click(function() 
    {
        var brontaal= $("#bron-taal option:selected").val();
        var doeltaal= $("#doel-taal option:selected").val();
        if(brontaal==doeltaal)
            {alert("De gewenste talen moeten verschillend zijn")}
        var vg= $("#vakgebied option:selected").val();
        var aantal=$("#aantal").val();
        var taal = brontaal+"-"+doeltaal;

        //var prijzen= {"NL-DE":0.15,"DE-NL":0.20};
        var prijzen= <?php echo json_encode($prijs);?>;
        var vakgebied= <?php echo json_encode($vak);?>;
         if(aantal > maxdata)
                {
                 alert("Het aantal woorden die u heeft ingetypt is over de maximum");   

                }
        else
        {
            var totaal= prijzen[taal][vg] * aantal;
            var totaal = totaal.toFixed(2); 
            $("#resultaat").text("De prijs van "+aantal+" woorden "+"met "+vg+"      Als vakgebied is "+totaal+" euro's").hide().fadeIn(900);

        }
        //document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML=
        //alert(); 

    });  


});            
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var maxdata;
  $("#vakgebied").on('change', function(){ 
        var current = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
        //alert(current);
        maxdata = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-max');
        //alert(maxdata);
        $("#maxwoorden").text("MaxWoordenPerDag: "+ maxdata);
  }); 

  $("#berekenen").click(function() {
    //code
     if(aantal > maxdata){
       alert("Het aantal woorden die u heeft ingetypt is over de maximum");
     }
     else{ // code}
  });  
});
```